# How to Fix ''Level None not found' Error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Facing following error when running code

`Level None not found`

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index = 'User Name',values = ['Threat Score', 'Score'], 
        aggfunc = {
                   'Threat Score': np.mean,
                   'Score' :[np.mean, lambda x: len(x.dropna())]
                  }, 
        margins = True) 
pt = pt.sort_values('Score', ascending = False)
```

I want to take the average value of `Threat Score` & `Score`, also count of the user name.  Then sort by `Threat Score` high to low.

Comment: Are there any repeating values in column name call `User Name`

Comment: @DinushaDilanka Yes, one value can be there for more than 2 time also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in pandas this is a [github link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12210) for the same. This error comes with with multiple aggregations per column and `margins=True`, it won't come if you choose flag `margins = False`. you can add them later if you want. That sure will work:

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index = 'User Name',values = ['Threat Score', 'Score'], 
        aggfunc = {
                   'Threat Score': np.mean,
                   'Score' :[np.mean, lambda x: len(x.dropna())]
                  }, 
        margins = False) 
pt = pt.sort_values('Score', ascending = False)
```

let me know if this works for you

Comment: now getting the following error. ValueError: The column label 'Score' is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index = 'User Agent', values = ['Threat Score', 'Score','Source IP'] ,  
                    aggfunc = {"Source IP" : 'count',
                               'Threat Score':np.mean,
                               'Score': np.mean})

pt = pt.sort_values('Threat Score', ascending = False) 
new_cols = ['Avg_Score', 'Count', 'Avg_ThreatScore']
pt.columns = new_cols
pt.to_csv(Path3 + '\\AllUserAgent.csv')
```